# How to random without errors inside a while loop?

Tags: java, random, while-loop

I have a public double method: bisectie with 2 double parameters, When I random in a range using those parameters , I ve got some errors I can t deal with them.

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at BisectieOptimizata.bisectie(BisectieOptimizata.java:23)
    at BisectieOptimizata.main(BisectieOptimizata.java:39) "
```

Below is the source code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class BisectieOptimizata {

    public  double c;
    public double eps = 0.01;

    //test function
    public double functie(double x){
        return x*x - 2*x + 1;
    }
    //derivata
    public double derivata(double x){
        return (functie(x+eps)-functie(x))/eps;
    }
    //bisection algh.
    public double bisectie(double a, double b){

        Random rand = new Random();
        double err = 0.001;

        while(Math.abs(b-a)>err){

            c = rand.nextInt((int)((b - a) + 1)) + a + rand.nextDouble(); // random a number from a range, ex: [-10;11), I random 4.542 

            if(derivata(c)<0){
                if(derivata(c)<a) a = c-a;
                else a = c;
            }else {
                if(derivata(c)>b) b = c-b;
                else b = c;

            }
        }
        return (a+b)/2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        BisectieOptimizata BO = new BisectieOptimizata();
        System.out.println(BO.bisectie(-10, 10)); // a = -10, b = 10
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears `(int)((b - a) + 1)` results in a value < 1.

Comment: @JoshM : it s got nothing to do with that, I made a test, where I replaced my parameters a with -10 and b with 10 directly inside c = rand.nextInt((int)((b - a) + 1)) + a + rand.nextDouble() and it s working fine

Comment: I beg to differ... Stacktraces don't lie.

Comment: What you said is confirming what Josh points out.

Comment: The moment `a` > `b+1`, it will result in a value of <= 0.

Comment: @ Amir Afghani: don t understand, sorry

Comment: @ Josh M: a it s always equals to -10, so a is never > b + 1

Comment: @VladRadulescu - See my answer.  The argument to nextInt cannot be a negative number.  Add the print statement I suggested to see how your program always fails when the expression is negative

Comment: Yes, please actually read the exception message.  I know you may find this hard to believe, but those words actually mean something!

Comment: yes, ty all, I did the print statement test, and I found where the problem was, again ty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observed that you are comparing (Math.abs(b - a) > err) so a negative number can 
also be greater than 0.001 as it is Math.abs.

This will cause your value inside rand.nextInt() to go negative.

The values of a and b change as follows in the program

```
10.0
-10.0

10.0
-2.5993084021357675

0.1896164396715161
-2.5993084021357675

0.1896164396715161    
1.5161487751844813  ---> error
```

Here (a-b)+1 = -0.32653233551. Now the Math.abs(b - a) value is 1.32653233551 which obviously qualifies the loop criterion.

But when the value (a-b)+1 is passed into rand.nextInt(), it will generate an exception as the number is negative.

I am not sure what you are doing with the algorithm, but removing Math.abs does solve the problem.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply, i`ve made some System.out.println help stmts and you are right, in one point i have a negative number inside the .nextInt(). Off topic, I need that (Math.abs(b - a) > err) in order to resolve my algh. find in optimal way a solution to a unimodal function (such as x*x + 2*x + 1 => solution x1=x2=-1)

Comment: You should notice that rand.nextInt would require a positive integer and even 0 is not allowed. So once your a-b goes below 1, you should probably eliminate the term?
I believe you are adding the 1 to solve this problem, but it wont work because according to your logic eventually they will go below 1.

Answer (score 0):

The exception provides meaningful information:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at BisectieOptimizata.bisectie(BisectieOptimizata.java:23)
    at BisectieOptimizata.main(BisectieOptimizata.java:39) "
```

So, have you ensured that the argument to `nextInt` is positive wherever you use it in your code?  It appears not.

```
rand.nextInt((int)((b - a) + 1)) + a + rand.nextDouble();
```

Perhaps you forgot to perform `Math.abs` here?  Without more information, it's hard to know.  Debugging this problem in an IDE would be easy.  You can set an 'Exception Breakpoint' in Intellij, and catch your program at the point in which this exception is thrown, and examine the call stack and variables available in memory.

Or just add this print statement before your call to `nextInt`:

```
        System.out.println((int)((b - a) + 1));
```

and you'll notice it only fails when the value of the expression is negative.

Comment: in my case rand.nextInt((int)((b - a) + 1)) is > 0, I made this test and it s working fine: double b=10;
  double a=-10;
  Random rand = new Random();
  double c = rand.nextInt((int)(b - a) + 1) + a + rand.nextDouble(); System.out.println("sectiunea c: " + c);